# STG_E_REVERTED after SharePoint migration to 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

We have a number of lists that return a STG_E_REVERTED error when you attempt to view them in SharePoint 2013.  It is specific to certain libraries in a site, so I don't think it is not a master page problem.  I have read that a corrupt view can provide this result, but I get the same error if I create a new view with just the title field.

I don't know if this is relevant, but I found this interesting.  The list works correctly on the SharePoint 2010 server.  However you can not query the items from the 2010 list using Powershell.  If you attempt to query the ItemCount you get zero, even though you can see items through the GUI.  If you you query the list properties it you this incomplete results.

```
EffectiveRawPermissions   :
EffectiveAuditMask        :
ProgID                    :
ParentFolder              : HR
ParentWeb                 : <EDITED>
Url                       : HR/Employee DocsForm
UniqueId                  :
ItemCount                 :
Name                      : Employee DocsForm
ServerRelativeUrl         : /HR/Employee DocsForm
WelcomePage               :
Files                     : {}
SubFolders                : {}
ContainingDocumentLibrary : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
RequiresCheckout          : False
DocumentLibrary           :
Exists                    : False
Item                      :
Properties                :
Audit                     : Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAudit
ParentListId              : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
UniqueContentTypeOrder    :
ContentTypeOrder          :
```

Answer (score 0):

This was finally bounced to Microsoft Support.   It turned on that when the data was migrated from SP2007 to SP2010, some of the fields failed the migration.  These fields were not critical in SP2010, but are required in SP2013.  Microsoft provided a script to resolve the problem.  So this was a few months ago, and I no longer have any more details.